# Trying to get a different in date with mysql and sqlite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For my application, I'm using Laravel and trying to figure out how I can adjust this query because in development I"m using MySQL but for testing, I'm using SQLite. The problem is that I can't use DATEDIFF for SQLite. Does anyone have a suggestion on what I should do to retrieve the champion with the longest title length?

```
return Champion::with('team')
        ->select(\DB::raw('DATEDIFF(IFNULL(DATE(champions.lost_on), '. Carbon::now()->toDateString().'), DATE(champions.won_on)) as length, team_id'))
        ->where('title_id', $title->id)
        ->orderBy('length', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('length', 'team_id')
        ->first();
```

Comment: And you really need to test if this works? Or you want to test something with the data you get back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite you can use

> julianday('now') - julianday(DateCreated)

Comment: I guess he googled that as well. I think OP wants something that will handle SQLite as well as MySQL.